# Set partial text in kendo grid column to bold

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm having a kendo grid with lots of text in the columns.
Lately i've managed to get linebreaks and multiline working correctly like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38198084/how-to-set-multiline-column-in-kendo-ui-grid)

Now i'm wondering if it is possible to set parts of the text in the grid to bold like

"**FirstBold:** FirstNonBold \n

**2ndBold:** 2ndNonBold \n ... "

Comment: Do you mean something like [this](http://dojo.telerik.com/enEKi/6) ?

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for. Thank you!